# Firebase Pub/Sub function sets false cloud scheduler region

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am creating a Firebase Pub/Sub function scheduledFunction for which the region is set to "europe-west1".

```
export scheduledFunction = 
    region("europe-west1")
        .pubsub
        .schedule("* * * * *")
        .timeZone("Europe/Berlin")
        .onRun((context) => {
          [...]
        });
```

I am also setting the functions region in `firebase.json` to "europe-west1".

```
"functions": {
    "source": "functions",
    "region": "europe-west1"
  }
```

However the region of the Job in the Google Cloud Scheduler gets set to us-central1.

[image]

Setting the location to "europe-west1" for a Http function works fine. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding you wanted to change the region from the **project** that is set from us-central1 to europe-west1.

According to this [documentation](https://medium.com/google-cloud/a-first-glance-at-google-cloud-scheduler-60554bc3cff7)

---

> Note: The region cannot be changed later on.

---

Once you set the region in your **project** you can't change it.

Another way around I found is to create a new Cloud Scheduler and indicate in the region you needed for the project.

Hope it helps